# from x import y ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'x'

Tags: python, flask, python-unittest

I have included my app's API key in a file named privateinfo.py but have .gitignored it for security purposes. I imported the key info into my init.py file but when I unittest my application, I receive this error,
"**from .privateinfo import key ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.privateinfo**'"

This is how I am importing the key into init.py file

```
from .privateinfo import key
```

Here is a photo of how my directory is set up:

[image]

As you can see, the privateinfo file as well as the init file are both in the app directory while .gitignore is in the root directory.

Comment: 1) can you please share the code snippet, it would be easier to help you 2) try `from . import key`

Comment: I have listed the code in my question

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your code: You must be running file individually, maybe for testing. In such cases, python doesn't recognise it as a module.

Here is a solution.

Write: `from app.privateinfo import key`

Note: Remember that this will work only when you run it from outside. i.e. file in which you wrote above statement must be any of the files from `config, forms, models, run`.

For Running a file individually:
Let's say you wrote above import statement in file `refactor.py` and you want to test it. Just create a file `runner.py` outside `app` and write `import app.refactor`. Now execute `runner.py`

Explanation: This will run `refactor` while considering `app` as module, thus, your imports will work.

Comment: My issue is that I am unittesting my code (not running the application) and receiving the aforementioned error. I need to import the key into the init file because that is where the API is being used. The init file and the privateinfo file are both in the app directory which is why I formatted it as ".privateinfo import key" for relative importing.

Comment: Ohh.. then its simple. Just run: `python3 -m unittest` from root directory.

Answer (score 0):

In your app `__init__.py` add `from .app import *`

Then, in your tests file you can import your `app` package. The `__init__.py` in your tests can be empty; it's there to define the tests as a different package.

For example, in your test file, you can change your import statement to `from app.privateinfo import key`.

The `app` and `tests` are considered different modules; when you import another module, you import *what is defined in its `__init__.py`*. If your app `__init__.py` is empty you basically load nothing from that module.